# I can not see the response of the web service through the swagger

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-services, swagger

I have a problem with swagger. I made a web service that is invoked by web page. There, the information returned is visible, but when I want to see it through swagger (because I need to check this in both places), it shows this error

[image]

It's my second web service that I do in Python, I've been doing it at the tip of my heart and reading Google, so I know it's not the best or the most beautiful.
Here I leave the code of my page and the code of the python to read their opinions:

```
from app import APP
import cx_Oracle
import json
from flask import render_template, request, jsonify
import log
import database
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource, fields

with open('./config/config_countries.json', 'r') as config_file:
    config = json.load(config_file)

with open('./config/config_general.json', 'r') as config_file:
    config_general = json.load(config_file)

global max_return
global log_tag
log_tag = config["CONFIG"]["LOG_TAG"]
srv_name = config["CONFIG"]["LOG_TAG"]
desc = config["CONFIG"]["DESCRIPTION"]
profile_name = config["CONFIG"]["PROFILE_NAME"]
conn_str = config_general["CONFIG"]["DB"]
max_return = config_general["CONFIG"]["MAX_RETURN"]
limite = config_general["CONFIG"]["LIMIT_PER_SECOND"]

log.init(profile_name)
log.dbg('Start')
database.init()

api = Api(APP, version='1.0', title=srv_name,
          description=desc + '\n'
                             'Database:' + conn_str + '\n'
                                                           'Max request by second:' + limite)

ns = api.namespace('getCountries', description='getCountries Predictions')

@APP.route('/getCountries', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@ns.response(200, 'Success')
@ns.response(404, 'Not found')
@ns.response(429, 'Too many request')
@ns.param('country', 'Substring Country (ej:ARGE)')
def getCountries():
    try:
        list_parametros = (request.get_json())
        country = list_parametros["country"]
        cur = database.db.cursor()
        list = cur.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
        cur.callproc('PREDICTIVO.get_country', (country, max_return, list))
    except Exception as e:
        database.init()
        if database.db is not None:
            log.inf('Reconexion OK')
            cur = database.db.cursor()
            list = cur.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
            cur.callproc('PREDICTIVO.get_country', (country, max_return, list))
        else:
            log.err('Connection Fail')
            list = None
    response = list.getvalue()
    return json.dumps(response), 200
```

And html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input list="lista_paises" id="pais" type="text" placeholder="Pais"/>
        <datalist id="lista_paises"></datalist><br />
    </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    $("#pais").keyup(function (e) {
        if ($("#pais").val().length > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5100/getCountries',
                data: JSON.stringify({ "country": $("#pais").val() }),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log('RESPUESTA:' + response);
                    var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(response);
                    var options = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < parsedJSON.list_pais.length; i++) {
                        options += '<option value="' + parsedJSON.list_pais[i].pais + '" />';
                    }
                    document.getElementById('lista_paises').innerHTML = options;
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        } else {
                 document.getElementById('lista_paises').innerHTML = '';
        }
    });

    // ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console? Can you also post the content of the `http://127.0.0.1:5100/swagger.json` file?

Comment: This?

`{"swagger": "2.0", "basePath": "/", "paths": {}, "info": {"title": "Microservicio getCountries", "version": "1.0", "description": "Microservicio predictivo para paises\nConexi\u00f3n a BD:VUC/vuc1234@alejo\nCantidad m\u00e1xima de invocaciones por segundo:4"}, "produces": ["application/json"], "consumes": ["application/json"], "tags": [], "responses": {"ParseError": {"description": "When a mask can't be parsed"}, "MaskError": {"description": "When any error occurs on mask"}}}`